# Running Excel VBA from MS Access VBA

Tags: vba

Spent some time researching and I cannot figure out whats wrong.

Security Settings in both files are correct. The sub being called is public & in a normal module.

The error states "Cannot run macro blah blah blah...."

Code:

```
Private Sub this()
    Dim xl As Object
    Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xl.Visible = True
    xl.Workbooks.Open "pathToFile" & "\" & "Dig IT.xlsm", True, False
    xl.Run "ThisWorkbook.Module3"
    Set xl = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Ah god im dumb. Changed it to xl.Run "name" and it worked perfectly. Post as answer and receive feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `"ThisWorkbook.Module3"`, you need to supply the workbook name, module name, and procedure name (assuming "Module3" is the name of the *code module*, not the sub/function that you're trying to run).

I believe that should be in the format like this (untested):

```
Private Sub this()
    Dim xl As Object, wb as Object
    Const MODULE_NAME As String = "Module3"  '### MODIFY AS NEEDED! 
    Const PROC_NAME As String = "macro_name" '### MODIFY AS NEEDED! 
    Dim xlMacro As String
    Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xl.Visible = True
    Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open("pathToFile" & "\" & "Dig IT.xlsm", True, False)

    ' builds the string to send to Excel.Run method:
    xlMacro = wb.Name & "!" & MODULE_NAME & "." & PROC_NAME
    ' call the macro in Excel
    xl.Run xlMacro
    Set xl = Nothing
End Sub
```